# how to remove setup page magento 2

Tags: setup, magento2.2.6

I'm using 2.2.6,

How to remove setup page magento 2 when installed after

like http://xxxx.com/setup/index.php/session/unlogin

thank you!

Comment: you can redirect it to your home page OR restrict for other IP Address, by NGINX configuration.